# Variational Encoder on typical PCA task

Tags: autoencoders, variational

I have just started to learn about variational autoencoders.
As a first step I have tried doing a task with both PCA and VA.
However, the VA results are very poor. Does anybody see any quick fixes that can be made to the VA code in order for VA to give more accurate results? Am I for example missing completely on the neuron numbers, hidden layer numbers or the activation functions?

The code is heavily based on chapter 17 in Geron's notebook: https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2.
I'va basically just changed the activation functions to reu and linear.

edit1: Added examples of what I think might be wrong/bad.

**Modules**

```
# Python ≥3.5 is required
import sys
assert sys.version_info >= (3, 5)

# Scikit-Learn ≥0.20 is required
import sklearn
assert sklearn.__version__ >= "0.20"

try:
    # %tensorflow_version only exists in Colab.
    %tensorflow_version 2.x
    IS_COLAB = True
except Exception:
    IS_COLAB = False

# TensorFlow ≥2.0 is required
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
assert tf.__version__ >= "2.0"

if not tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'):
    print("No GPU was detected. LSTMs and CNNs can be very slow without a GPU.")
    if IS_COLAB:
        print("Go to Runtime > Change runtime and select a GPU hardware accelerator.")

# Common imports
import numpy as np
import os
from pathlib import Path

# to make this notebook's output stable across runs
np.random.seed(42)
tf.random.set_seed(42)
```

**Data**

```
np.random.seed(4)

def generate_3d_data(m, w1=0.1, w2=0.3, noise=0.1):
    angles = np.random.rand(m) * 3 * np.pi / 2 - 0.5
    data = np.empty((m, 3))
    data[:, 0] = np.cos(angles) + np.sin(angles)/2 + noise * np.random.randn(m) / 2
    data[:, 1] = np.sin(angles) * 0.7 + noise * np.random.randn(m) / 2
    data[:, 2] = data[:, 0] * w1 + data[:, 1] * w2 + noise * np.random.randn(m)
    #data = data - data.mean(axis=0, keepdims=0)
    return data

X_train = generate_3d_data(60)
X_train = X_train - X_train.mean(axis=0, keepdims=0)
```

**PCA**

```
np.random.seed(42)
tf.random.set_seed(42)

encoder = keras.models.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(2, input_shape=[3])])
decoder = keras.models.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(3, input_shape=[2])])
autoencoder = keras.models.Sequential([encoder, decoder])

autoencoder.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1.5))

history = autoencoder.fit(X_train, X_train, epochs=20)

codings = encoder.predict(X_train)

X_trainDecoded = decoder.predict(codings)

# Print
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': lambda x: "{0:0.0f}".format(x)})
print('\nPercentage difference decoded and original data:')
print((X_trainDecoded/X_train-1)*100)

print("\nAverage percentage difference: ", np.mean((X_trainDecoded/X_train-1)*100))
```

PCA output

```
Epoch 20/20
    60/60 [==============================] - 0s 69us/sample - loss: 0.0054

Average percentage difference:  17.894847248764663
```

**VA**

```
K = keras.backend

class Sampling(keras.layers.Layer):
    def call(self, inputs):
        mean, log_var = inputs
        return K.random_normal(tf.shape(log_var)) * K.exp(log_var / 2) + mean 
    
tf.random.set_seed(42)
np.random.seed(42)

# The new dimension (lower than dimension of input data)
codings_size = 2

# Layers before the stochastic part
inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=[X_train[0].shape[0]])                 
z = keras.layers.Flatten()(inputs)                                       
z = keras.layers.Dense(150, activation="relu")(z)                        
z = keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu")(z)                        

# Stochastic part
codings_mean = keras.layers.Dense(codings_size)(z)                       
codings_log_var = keras.layers.Dense(codings_size)(z)                    
# Sampling
codings = Sampling()([codings_mean, codings_log_var])
# Encoder set as an own model: Inputs and outputs specified.
variational_encoder = keras.models.Model(
    inputs=[inputs], outputs=[codings_mean, codings_log_var, codings]) 

# Decoding of the stochastic outout
decoder_inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=[codings_size])      
x = keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu")(decoder_inputs) 
x = keras.layers.Dense(150, activation="relu")(x)              
x = keras.layers.Dense(X_train[0].shape[0] * 1, activation="linear")(x)
outputs = keras.layers.Reshape([X_train[0].shape[0]])(x)     
variational_decoder = keras.models.Model(inputs=[decoder_inputs], outputs=[outputs]) 

# Merge encoder and decoder models
_, _, codings = variational_encoder(inputs)                    
reconstructions = variational_decoder(codings)                 
# Full model = encoder + reconstruction
variational_ae = keras.models.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[reconstructions])

# Loss function
latent_loss = -0.5 * K.sum(
    1 + codings_log_var - K.exp(codings_log_var) - K.square(codings_mean),
    axis=-1)
# Add loss function to full model
variational_ae.add_loss(K.mean(latent_loss) / X_train[0].shape[0]) 
# Loss and optimzer
variational_ae.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="rmsprop") 

# Fit
history = variational_ae.fit(X_train, X_train, epochs=50, batch_size=128, validation_split=0.1 )

# Reconstruction
tf.random.set_seed(42)
reconstructions = variational_ae.predict(X_train)
print((reconstructions/X_train-1)*100)
print('\nAverage percentage difference: ', np.mean((reconstructions/X_train-1)*100))
```

VA output

```
Average percentage difference:  97.2531197324568
```

Comment: Can you describe the actual task that is being solved?

Comment: @AleksejsFomins: I added examples of what I think can possibly be changed to make VA work better.